# Splitting an integer into smaller integers of defined sizes in Python

Tags: python

I need to split an integer value of arbitrary size into smaller integers (chunks), and do it in the most efficient way. The chunks sizes I have are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16.

Let's say I need to split an integer 45: The chunks I would have would be: 16, 16, 8, 4, 1.
How would I write a Python function to do that for me?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: By chunks you mean smaller numbers that add up to the given number?

Comment: There are many similar but highly scored questions because that does not mean the OP is necessarily lazy but simply because he does not know where to start or how to do it @Rogalski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the chunks you said, a greedy solution will work, here's a working solution:

```
def split_number(n, sizes):
    sizes = sorted(sizes, reverse=True)
    ret = {}

    for size in sizes:
        if size <= n:
            ret[size], n = divmod(n, size)

    return ret

print split_number(45, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16])
```

Given arbitrary sizes the problem is called knapsack problem, which is NP-Hard

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the given number to its binary equivalent and reconvert the binary term by term to decimal. This way 45 = 32 + 8 + 4 + 1. Since 32 is not allowed you just split it to 16+16

A code is given below :

```
quotient = int(input("Enter a number: "))
count=0
result=[]
while quotient != 0:
    remainder = quotient%2
    quotient = quotient//2   
    count +=1
    result.append(remainder)
n=0
while n<len(result):
    chunk=result[n]*2**(n)
    if chunk <=16:
        print (chunk,end=' ')
    else:
        q=chunk/16
        for times in range(int(q)):
            print (16,end=' ')
    n=n+1
print('\n')
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It seems that you have some 3s and 6s in the chunks though... But the idea is right.